# HTML/CSS/Javascript adding tracking cookies to script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cookies

So I've had a friend help me with building a script that will auto play music, include a mute button without all the extra business, and loops.. however it doesn't loop through the navigation of the page. Meaning when you navigate the website to other pages, the music restarts. So I'm wondering, what cookies I need to put in and where, because my prior cookies were apparently causing an issue with the mute button somehow. **So, what do I add to track when the music is delayed and to add a cookie that resumes when it was last played?** So that when the user clicks another page in the same site, the music doesn't start over, and resumes playing from it's last play point. I'll also include the code I had before that used cookies, maybe there's a way to mix the 2 together to have the sound button and continuous music flow?

```
<audio tabindex="0" id="Backgroundmusic" controls preload="auto" >
    <source src="http://bdo-mfh.weebly.com/files/theme/InstrumentalCore-LetThereBeLight.mp3">
</audio>
    <a href="#" id="bn-sound"><img src="http://findicons.com/files/icons/772/token_light/256/sound.png" /></a>



<script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function() {
    playStream();
});
function playStream() {

        var player = document.getElementById('Backgroundmusic');

        (player.paused == true) ? toggle(0) : toggle(1);

        $('#bn-sound').click(function() {

            (player.paused == true) ? toggle(0) : toggle(1);

            return false;

        });

}

function toggle(state) {

        var player = document.getElementById('Backgroundmusic');
        var link = document.getElementById('bn-sound');
        var src = "http://bdo-mfh.weebly.com/files/theme/InstrumentalCore-LetThereBeLight.mp3";

        switch(state) {
                case 0:  
                        player.play();
                        $('#bn-sound').removeClass('sound-pause');
                        player_state = 1;
                        break;
                case 1:
                        player.pause();
                        player.currentTime = 0;
                        player.src = '';
                        $('#bn-sound').addClass('sound-pause');
                        player_state = 0;
                        break;
        }
}</script>

<style>.sound-pause {
    opacity: 0.2; 
}
#bn-sound {
    width: 40px;
    display: block;
}
#bn-sound img {
    width: 100%;
}
#Backgroundmusic {
    display: none;
}</style>
```

***Now for the previous code I had***

```
        <audio id= "Backgroundmusic" preload="auto" src="MUSIC.MP3" loop="true" autobuffer>
Unsupported in Firefox
</audio>
<a href="#noscroll" id="mute">toggle sound</a>

<script>

var audio = document.getElementById('Backgroundmusic');

document.getElementById('mute').addEventListener('click', function (e)
{
    e = e || window.event;
    audio.muted = !audio.muted;
    e.preventDefault();
}, false);

function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays)
{
    var exdate=new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
    var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
    document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
}

function getCookie(c_name)
{
    var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
    for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++)
    {
      x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
      y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
      x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
      if (x==c_name)
        {
        return unescape(y);
        }
      }
}

var song = document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0];
var played = false;
var tillPlayed = getCookie('timePlayed');
function update()
{
    if(!played){
        if(tillPlayed){
        song.currentTime = tillPlayed;
        song.play();
        played = true;
        }
        else {
                song.play();
                played = true;
        }
    }

    else {
    setCookie('timePlayed', song.currentTime);
    }
}
setInterval(update,1000);
</script>
```

Comment: best way is build a single page app so page never reloads, only different views do within the app

Comment: Have you ever consider using html5 local storage http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: No actually. Atm I'm only working with a limited web page builder, so I'm only able to use the confines of it mostly. I can't make a single web page(even if I wanted to), I did have a code before that worked.. it worked and had music plying through continuously... Cept for some reason, I couldn't have the sound button and etc like I have above with it. Idk why.